# Getting Dropbox - 403 error when logging on using dropboxuploader.php

Tags: dropbox

Hey I'm using dropboxuploader.php to login into dropbox. All was working fine, but when i came into work yesterday i could no longer connect. This is what dropbox is returning to me.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Thu, 04 Oct 2012 08:44:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

It seems you tried to do something we can't verify.  Did you log into a different Dropbox account in a different window?  Try clicking `<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;">here</a>` to go back to the page you came from, or just go `<a href="/home">home</a>.`

Comment: Can you add the code? (double, see @GeertJaminon reply)

Comment: $uploader = new DropboxUploader($_REQUEST['DropboxDetails']['Username']  , $_REQUEST['DropboxDetails']['Password'] );
  $uploader->login();

Comment: In the code above all i'm doing is calling the login function in dropboxuploader.php

Comment: I have issues with the login view of the iOS SDK since today resultier in 403. Could be related to https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=91259 . You might Post this in the dropbox dev forums, as well.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, i posted here on https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=91285#post-501800 yesterday evening.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the login function with below code and it should work:

```
protected function login() {
    $data = $this->request('https://www.dropbox.com/login');

    $str = '<input type="hidden" name="t" value="';
    $start = strpos($data,$str);

    $val = "";
    if($start !== false)
    {

        $val = substr($data,$start+strlen($str),24);
    }

    $data = $this->request('https://www.dropbox.com/login', true, array('login_email'=>$this->email, 'login_password'=>$this->password, 't'=>$val));

    if (stripos($data, 'location: /home') === false)
        throw new Exception('Login unsuccessful.');

    $this->loggedIn = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your dropbox uploader file instead doing your fixes.

https://github.com/jakajancar/DropboxUploader