# Getting 403 error when trying to parse dropbox events page with python and mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, dropbox, http-status-code-403, scrape

I use this script to get a list of all file updates to a certain directory. I then parse that list to get a list of time slots I have been active in that directory. That way I can quickly see how much time I have spent on the project and know what to charge my client.

I have written a small python script, adapted from this: https://github.com/jncraton/PythonDropboxUploader

I added the bottom function to retrieve a specific events page from https://www.dropbox.com/events?ns=false&n=50

I have used the script before 2 months ago and it worked well, but now I am getting 403: forbidden errors on:

```
eventSrc = self.browser.open(req).read()
```

Probably DropBox tries to block scrapers like mine to push programmers to use their API instead, but unfortunately the API doesn't support listing the events.

Can anybody help me out to get it working again?

This is the python code to create the connection:

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import re
import json

class DropboxConnection:
""" Creates a connection to Dropbox """

email = ""
password = ""
root_ns = ""
token = ""
browser = None

def __init__(self, email, password):
    self.email = email
    self.password = password

    self.login()
    self.get_constants()

def login(self):
    """ Login to Dropbox and return mechanize browser instance """

    # Fire up a browser using mechanize
    self.browser = mechanize.Browser()

    self.browser.set_handle_equiv(False)
    self.browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
    self.browser.set_handle_referer(True)
    self.browser.set_handle_robots(False)

    self.browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20120722 Firefox/14.0.1')]

    # Browse to the login page
    self.browser.open('https://www.dropbox.com/login')

    # Enter the username and password into the login form
    isLoginForm = lambda l: l.action == "https://www.dropbox.com/login" and l.method == "POST"

    try:
        self.browser.select_form(predicate=isLoginForm)
    except:
        self.browser = None
        raise(Exception('Unable to find login form'))

    self.browser['login_email'] = self.email
    self.browser['login_password'] = self.password
    self.browser['t'] = "1230"

    # Send the form
    response = self.browser.submit()

def get_constants(self):
    """ Load constants from page """

    home_src = self.browser.open('https://www.dropbox.com/home').read()

    try:
        self.root_ns = re.findall(r"root_ns: (\d+)", home_src)[0]
        self.token = re.findall(r"TOKEN: '(.+)'", home_src)[0]
    except:
        raise(Exception("Unable to find constants for AJAX requests"))

def upload_file(self, local_file, remote_dir, remote_file):
    """ Upload a local file to Dropbox """

    if(not self.is_logged_in()):
        raise(Exception("Can't upload when not logged in"))

    self.browser.open('https://www.dropbox.com/')

    # Add our file upload to the upload form
    isUploadForm = lambda u: u.action == "https://dl-web.dropbox.com/upload" and u.method == "POST"

    try:
        self.browser.select_form(predicate=isUploadForm)
    except:
        raise(Exception('Unable to find upload form'))

    self.browser.form.find_control("dest").readonly = False
    self.browser.form.set_value(remote_dir, "dest")
    self.browser.form.add_file(open(local_file, "rb"), "", remote_file)

    # Submit the form with the file
    self.browser.submit()

def get_dir_list(self, remote_dir):
    """ Get file info for a directory """

    if(not self.is_logged_in()):
        raise(Exception("Can't download when not logged in"))

    req_vars = "ns_id=" + self.root_ns + "&referrer=&t=" + self.token

    req = urllib2.Request('https://www.dropbox.com/browse' + remote_dir, data=req_vars)
    req.add_header('Referer', 'https://www.dropbox.com/home' + remote_dir)

    dir_info = json.loads(self.browser.open(req).read())

    dir_list = {}

    for item in dir_info['file_info']:
        # Eliminate directories
        if(item[0] == False):
            # get local filename
            absolute_filename = item[3]
            local_filename = re.findall(r".*\/(.*)", absolute_filename)[0]

            # get file URL and add it to the dictionary
            file_url = item[8]
            dir_list[local_filename] = file_url

    return dir_list

def get_download_url(self, remote_dir, remote_file):
    """ Get the URL to download a file """

    return self.get_dir_list(remote_dir)[remote_file]

def download_file(self, remote_dir, remote_file, local_file):
    """ Download a file and save it locally """

    fh = open(local_file, "wb")
    fh.write(self.browser.open(self.get_download_url(remote_dir, remote_file)).read())
    fh.close()

def is_logged_in(self):
    """ Checks if a login has been established """
    if(self.browser):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getEventsPage(self, n):
    if(not self.is_logged_in()):
        raise(Exception("Can't get event page when not logged in"))

    url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/next_events'
    values = {'cur_page': n, 'ns_id': 'false'}
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = mechanize.Request(url, data)

    # print url + '?' + data

    eventSrc = self.browser.open(req).read()
    return eventSrc
```

And this is the loop that parses the events pages:

```
from dbupload import DropboxConnection
from getpass import getpass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime_consts as pdc
c = pdc.Constants()
p = pdt.Calendar(c)

email = "myemail@gmail.com"  # raw_input("Enter Dropbox email address:")
password = getpass("Enter Dropbox password:")

dateFile = open('all_file_updates.txt', "wb")
try:
    # Create the connection
    conn = DropboxConnection(email, password)
except:
    print("Connection failed")
else:
    print("Connection succesful")

n = 250
found = 0
while(n >= 0):
    eventsPageSrc = conn.getEventsPage(n)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(eventsPageSrc)

    table = soup.find("table", {"id": "events"})
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        link = row.find("a", href=re.compile('^https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/ProjectName'))
        if(link != None):
            dateString = row.find("td", attrs={'class': 'modified'}).string
            date = p.parse(dateString)
            dateFile.write('Date: ' + str(date) + '    file: ' + link.string + '\n')
            found = found + 1
    n = n - 1
    print 'page: ' + str(n) + ' Total found: ' + str(found)
```

Comment: Are you sure you gave it the right username/password combo?

Comment: Yes, when I change https to http in the events url, the HTML returned contains a list of my DropBox folders.
It is probably related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743873/getting-dropbox-403-error-when-logging-on-using-dropboxuploader-php

Comment: Question: why not use the dropbox API directly?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get a list of all file updates in the API. It supports uploading and downloading files and getting the revisions of a certain file, but I didn't see support for what I want to do: getting a list of all updates. The updates are available as an RSS feed, but not with enough history (~200 pages)

Answer (score 0):

In def get_constants(self): change

```
self.token = re.findall(r"TOKEN: '(.+)'", home_src)[0]
```

to

```
self.token = re.findall(r'TOKEN: "(.+)"', home_src)[0]
```

dropbox has changed the way it stores constants

Hope it helps.